# CRM 365 returns CommunicationException on every call

Tags: oauth-2.0, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I have a service that calls CRM 365. The authentication is done with OAuth resp. a bearer token. This worked like a charm but suddenly a CommunicationException is thrown on every call. Maybe this is due to the update of the CRM version to v9.

This is how I create my *IOrganizationService*:

```
var crmProxy = new OrganizationWebProxyClient(serviceUri, false)
                   {
                       HeaderToken = bearerToken
                   };
```

where *serviceUri* is something like https://mydomain.crm.dynamics.com/xrmservices/2011/organization.svc/web?SdkClientVersion=9.0.0.0

When I make a call against this proxy (like *ExecuteRequest* or *RetrieveMultiple*) a *CommunicationException* is thrown with the following message:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while making the HTTP request to
>   https://mydomain.crm.dynamics.com/xrmservices/2011/organization.svc/web?SdkClientVersion=9.0.0.0.
>   This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not
>   configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also
>   be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and
>   the server. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection
>   was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host

I already updated the CRM SDK assembly to version 9.0.2.4. Still not working.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Dynamics 365 v9.0 enforces TLS 1.2. To enforce TLS 1.2 in the application you have to call the following before making requests:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Alternatively you can switch to .Net 4.6 or above. In these versions TLS 1.2 is the default.

Comment: Glad you found the solution. The better approach is to use .NET 4.6. This should prevent future issues with hard-coding when CRM requires > TLS 1.2

Comment: Yes, but for some reasons upgrading to .NET 4.6 (and even to .NET 4.7.1) didn't work.. Only setting the security protocol explicitly to Tls12  did the job...